# Problem with a Script in Roblox Studio Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a script for Roblox Studio that acts as a computer where you need to input a password. However, When I input a passcode, nothings changes in the TextLabel. I've checked, and all the variables are set to the right thing.

Here is my code:

```
-- Define references to the TextBox and TextLabel objects
local textBox = script.Parent.Input
local textLabel = script.Parent.Output

-- Define passcode
local passcode = "Ol8s%w_"

-- Define function to update the TextLabel text
local function updateTextLabel()
    if textBox.Text == passcode then
        textLabel.Text = "Correct Passcode!"
    elseif textBox.Text == "" then
        textLabel.Text = "Please Insert Correct Passcode To Continue"
    else
        textLabel.Text = "Incorrect, Try Again"
        wait(3)
        textLabel.Text = ""
    end
end

-- Set initial TextLabel text
textLabel.Text = "Please Insert Correct Passcode To Continue"

-- Set up event listener for TextBox text changes
textBox:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(updateTextLabel)
```

Once you input the right password in a textbox, the text label should say "Correct Passcode" and if you input the wrong passcode, is should say "Inncorrect, Try Again" for 3 seconds, then go back to its deafault message. I've tried multiple wasy to fix this. Please Help Me.

Here is the setup

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that assuming that this code is in a server script, the content of the TextBox is not replicated to the server and therefore the server does not register the change. To fix this you should add a LocalScript that fires a RemoteEvent with the password when the text changes.

LocalScript:

```lua
-- Define references to the TextBox and TextLabel objects
local textBox = script.Parent.Input

-- Define function to update the TextLabel text
local function updateTextLabel()
    script.Parent.Password:FireServer(textBox.Text)
end


-- Set up event listener for TextBox text changes
textBox:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(updateTextLabel)
```

ServerScript:

```
-- Define references to the TextBox and TextLabel objects
local textLabel = script.Parent.Output

-- Define passcode
local passcode = "Ol8s%w_"

-- Define function to update the TextLabel text
local function updateTextLabel(player, password)
    if password == passcode then
        textLabel.Text = "Correct Passcode!"
    elseif password == "" then
        textLabel.Text = "Please Insert Correct Passcode To Continue"
    else
        textLabel.Text = "Incorrect, Try Again"
        wait(3)
        textLabel.Text = ""
    end
end

-- Set initial TextLabel text
textLabel.Text = "Please Insert Correct Passcode To Continue"

-- Listen to the remoteEvent
script.Parent.Password.OnServerEvent:Connect(updateTextLabel)
```

Structure:

[image: Instance Structure]

The one thing to be aware with an implementation like this is the client will fire the RemoteEvent **every** time the text changes. I would recommend having a button the user presses to send the password to prevent RemoteEvent spam.

Comment: Good, then this method should work.

Comment: How would I add the button and script to this?

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work. Is there a setting on any of the things I'm using that should be on or off?

Comment: Because you are running the script in workspace, you may need to move the localscript somewhere else to allow it to run, since by default, localscripts do not run while in workspace.

Comment: OK, now it works, but how would I integrate a button?

Comment: Instead of listening to the property changed of text on the textbox, you would listen to the MouseButton1Click event on a button